# LINQ filter list based on given conditions

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm currently working on a .NET application. I need to write a LINQ query to filter a `List<SearchResult>` given in the example below.

Allowed are the combinations of **CompanyId + ContactId** or **CompanyId (without ContactId)** as a key for the result, the entries in the result list must be **distinct**.

The key in the result list is a combination of unique "CompanyID + ContactId" OR unique "CompanyID". As an example, in the result list as a key I can have one "companyID 1", and several "companyID 1" + ContactID (1, 2, 3, ...) BUT eacht ContactID only one time in combination with one CompanyID i.e. `{1},{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}` but not a second time `{1, 1}` or `{1}`.

```
public class SearchResult
{
    public int? CompanyId {get; set;}
    public int? ContactId {get; set;}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var searchResults = new List<SearchResult>
        {
            new SearchResult { CompanyId = 1, ContactId = 1 }, // yes
            new SearchResult { CompanyId = 2, ContactId = 3 }, // yes
            new SearchResult { CompanyId = 2, ContactId = 4 }, // yes
            new SearchResult { CompanyId = 1 }, // yes
            new SearchResult { CompanyId = 2 }, // yes
            new SearchResult { CompanyId = 1, ContactId = 1 }, // no
            new SearchResult { CompanyId = 1 }, // no
            new SearchResult { }, // no
            new SearchResult { CompanyId = null }, // no
            new SearchResult { CompanyId = null, ContactId = null }, // no
            new SearchResult { ContactId = null }, // no
        };
        
        // Unfortunately my LINQ query doesn't work correctly 
        var result = searchResults
                      .GroupBy(sr => sr.CompanyId)
                      .Select(grp => grp.First());
        
        foreach(SearchResult sr in result){         
            Console.WriteLine(sr.CompanyId + " " + sr.ContactId);
        }
    }
}
```

My current LINQ query doesn't work correctly - it's also quite basic. I only get the result: `[{1, 1},{2, 3}]`, it's really tricky.

Though the desired result should be `[{1, 1},{2, 3},{2, 4}, {1},{2}]`.

Do you know how to retrieve the correct result?

Comment: Distinct values in the list itself or on a larger level? Should all company IDs be unique?

Comment: Why is `new SearchResult { CompanyId = 1, ContactId = 1 }, // no` - is the processing dependent on the order of the items?

Comment: on a larger level - the key is a combination of unique "CompanyID + ContactId" OR unique "CompanyID" alone... so in the list I can have one companyID 1, and several companyID 1 + ContactID (1, 2, 3, ... but eacht ContactID only one time)

Comment: new SearchResult { CompanyId = 1, ContactId = 1 }, is a dublicate - there is already another entry with the same CompanyId and ContactId

Comment: oups, my bad... It's removed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close, however `.GroupBy` both `CompanyId` and `ContactId` (instead of just `CompanyId`) & then get the non-dupes using `.First()`.

```
var result = searchResults
    .GroupBy(sr => new { sr.CompanyId, sr.ContactId })
    .Select(x => x.First());
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly! I was quite close actually haha.

Comment: @Bender. You're welcome! :)